# will singleton pattern work in a load balanced environment

Tags: singleton

while reading abt singleton pattern I had following query which I need help with:
assuming a singleton class contains some state / data
it is not an issue coz only a single object will be created
but in case of load balanced environments one object would be created for each server
in that case state / data inconsistency issue will appear
so I want to know if my understanding is correct or not and if it is correct than what is the workaround

Comment: based on other sources I could find on internet I could derive that singleton pattern is not relevant to typical web development context that I could think of. A singleton object created in typical web application does not store state information, it is just an object that has members that are fixed for entire life of the application

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue:

if you have multiple servers attached to the load balancer, each server will have a separate copy of the application, and in this case, you will have multiple instances of the singleton class.
So, **it doesn't work**, it will violate the singleton principle.